# How to import existing Objective C classes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I had been messing around with Swift for a while in XCode 6.0 DP to use it in my existing project. 
I am trying to access MyModel.h(My existing  Objective C Model object) from my ViewController.swift file. I wanted to import

`#import "MyModel.h"` to my Swift file. 
But I could not find how this can be done.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Comment: You cannot just use import MyModel. You need to create a Objective-C bridging header and write the "MyModel.h" in this. Now you may use it in your swift class.

Answer (score 93):

Posting the answer if it helps some one facing the same issue.

I found that a pretty straight forward solution for How to do this is given in the iOS Developer Library. Please refer to the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75

Apple Doc says:

> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your
>   Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those
>   files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a
>   Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to
>   an existing Swift app.

So I created `MyApp-Bridging-Header.h` file and just added the following line:

```
#import "MyModel.h"
```

Now it lets me use the model in my `ViewController.swift` as follows:

```
var myModel = MyModel()
myModel.name = "My name"
myModel.dobString = "11 March,2013"
println ("my model values: Name: \myModel.name and dob: \myModel.dobString")
```

FYI to anyone who is trying to figure this out. If you have to create the bridging file from scratch, you also have to specify a path to it in Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header.

Comment: If my model is constant, how do you change it?

Comment: Thanks to Apple it is not straight forward to create a bridging file, I guess it would be to much trouble for the Swifties to add an explicit command to do that. Really makes it hard to like Swift.

Comment: I did this to my Apple Watch Extension (in Swift) but i  get an "underclared type" when I try to use it. Not working for me (my main app is in Obj-C)

Comment: "FYI" is important

Answer (score 17):

In [Document said in to swift programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) There are no import statement.

[image]

Comment: That "No import statement" message is for importing Swift code into Swift code. The OP was asking about how to import Obj-C code into Swift code; this table clearly states that to do so you need a bridging header.

Answer (score 6):

To import into Swift app or in Objective C app that is creating a mixed-language app you need to create a bridging header you can refer [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78)

Its says

> Objective-C and Swift files can coexist in a single project, whether the project was originally an Objective-C or Swift project. You can simply add a file of the other language directly to an existing project. This natural workflow makes creating mixed-language app and framework targets as straightforward as creating an app or framework target written in a single language.
>
> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to an existing Swift app.

EDIT:
I have created a code for your help you can find it [here](https://github.com/rohity821/ObjCWithSwiftCode)

Comment: Thank you for the repo. XCode did not suggest to add bridging header so I had to go to build settings and add SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = path to the header I created. Could not find that setting without your repo.