# How to import "UIButton+AFNetworking.h"(Obejctive-C category file) in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

`import UIButton+AFNetworking` would lead to an error, we cannot use *+* after import in Swift.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76

Comment: @duci9y , thanks, I have created Objective-C bridging header, but I don't know how to import the category

Comment: `#import "UIButton+AFNetworking.h"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not import the Objective-C file in Swift by simply `#import` statement. You need to create Objective-C bridging header and import the file in this bridging header. Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034409/how-to-import-existing-objective-c-classes-in-swift). This explains how you can import Objective-C file into Swift.

Comment: have created Objective-C bridging header, but I don't know how to import the category file, I mean that `import UIButton+AFNetworking` would lead to an error, I don't mean that I just use `#import` in Swift

Comment: You need to write `#import "UIButton+AFNetworking.h"`

Comment: the bridging header is in obj-c