# Integrate Objective- C library into Swift project?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I Need to use a Objective C library in my swift Project. 
I have referred this [How to import existing Objective C classes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034409/how-to-import-existing-objective-c-classes-in-swift)

So i copied all the files her https://github.com/liuminqian/SvpplyTable/tree/master/SvpplyTable to my Swift project. After that I created MyApp-Bridging-Header.h file.

Now how can i make this library work in my Project?

Comment: Drag and drop the library into your project. Be sure to select "Copy items if needed" before clicking Finished. Then import the library/ class e.g. #import "Example.com" and then you can create an instance of that to you or class methods directly.

Answer (score 1):

The bridging file will expose everything it imports in Swift. Just use the classes however you'd use them. E.g.

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass

- (void)doSomething;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) NSNumber *someNumber;

@end
```

MyProject-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

SomeClass.swift:

```
let instanceOfClass = MyClass()
instanceOfClass.doSomething()
print("Ended up with \(instanceOfClass.someNumber)")
```

Comment: I am very new to Xcode & specially to Obj-C. So please guide me how to add that library.  I don't know which file i have to call in the swift file. This is my current File Structure. http://i.imgur.com/jHHh5hy.png