# import swift linked objc class in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, objc-bridging-header

The project I work currently has Both Objective-C and Swift linked with the bridging header and everything works fine. but in one case where this particular viewController.h which is in Obj-c has swift imported already. when I try to access this viewController.h in another Swift controller it says '<#project-name#>-swift.h' file not found

Guide me how can I access this objC file in swift :(

**Edited:** detailed!!

I have a viewController.h file where I have implemented swift models by importing '<#project-name#>-swift.h'

but when I try to access this viewController.h from SecondViewController.swift, I have to add this `#import "viewController.h"` to the bridging header of my project. If I do so I am getting this error 
**'<#project-name#>-swift.h' file not found**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Objective C classes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034409/how-to-import-existing-objective-c-classes-in-swift)

Comment: Please check the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist

Comment: @Ved :: have updated my question...my issue is not on bridging header..but on reusing objc in swift which has bridging header.h imported!! Already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of what you are doing is correct, the problem is that the `projectname-Swift.h` header is included in a header (`viewController.h`) that is in turn imported in the bridging header.

The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122 talks about including the generated `*-Swift.h` header in `.m` files, not in headers, suggesting it should not be included in headers to avoid circular dependencies.  You can still get away with including it in a header, but that will break if the header is included in the bridging header.

I would import `*-Swift.h` in `viewController.m`, not `viewController.h`.  If you need to reference a Swift type as a property, argument, or return type in `viewController.h`, then you can use forward declarations, like

```
@class MySwiftModelClass;
```

If classes declared in `viewController.h` extend `MySwiftModelClass`, then things get a little trickier.  Please post a more specific brief example if that is the case.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer. pretty much You got what I was looking for... YES the documentation from apple says to import the bridging header to .m file to avoid circular dependencies.. Yes My class extends the swift in .h (my headers has some methods which returns a swift model)